# How to get rid of Runtime error 91 Object variable or with block variable not Set?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to call a function I created and I keep receiving this error.

```
 'This is where I try and call the function
 Sub Test1()
 Dim ChartCells1 As Range
 Set ChartCells1 = GetValues(ActiveSheet.Range("BV2", Range("BV2").End(xlDown)), ActiveSheet.Range("BV2"))
 ChartCells1.Select
 End Sub

'this is the function  am trying to call   
Function GetValues(Column As Range, Value As Range) As Range

Dim ChartCells As Range
Dim Count As Range
Dim Cells As Range
Dim Number As Range

DataSheetArea1Zone16.Activate

Set Number = Range(Value)
Set Cells = Range(Column)
Set ChartCells = Range(Value).Offset(0, -36)

For Each Count In Cells

  If Count.Value <> Number Then
    Set ChartCells = Union(ChartCells, Count.Offset(0, -36))
    Set Number = Count

  End If

Next Count

GetValues = ChartCells

End Function
```

'''

I keep receiving the error 91 but I  would  like for certain boxes to become selected

Comment: What line throws the error? From a quick glance: `Range(Value)` and `Range(Column)` are problematic. `Value` and `Column` are `Range`s already and shouldn't be enclosed in a `Range` call.

Comment: `GetValues = ChartCells` looks suspect too, if `GetValues` returns a `String`.

Comment: Your first problem is the way you've define your first argument you're passing to GetValues.  If your starting cell is BV2, it should be `ActiveSheet.Range("BV2", Range("BV2").End(xlDown))`.

Comment: Your second problem is that your `Next` control variable in GetValues should be `Next Count`, not `Next Count1`.

Comment: The third problem is that It looks like the return type for GetValues should be a Range object.  If so, the signature should be `Function GetValues(Column As Range, Value As Range) As Range`.

Comment: And, if the return type is indeed a Range object, you'll need to use the keyword Set in order to assign a Range object to your variable `Set ChartCells1  = GetValues(...).